# Handling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with ActionController::Metal

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm on the developing (JSON) API stage and decide to inherit my `ApiController` from `ActionController::Metal` to took advantages of speed etc.

So I've included a bunch of modules to make it work.

Recently I've decide to respond with empty result when record not found. Rails already throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` from `Model#find` method and I've been trying to use `rescue_from` to catch it and write something like this:

```
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ActionController::Metal
    # bunch of included modules 

    include ActiveSupport::Rescuable

    respond_to :json

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
      binding.pry
      respond_to do |format|
        format.any { head :not_found }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After call my simple action

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

And execution never reach `rescue_from`. It's throws:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with id=1
```

into my log file.

I've been trying it and in production mode. Server responds with 404 but response body is standard **HTML** error page for **JSON** request.

It's works well when I change inheritance from `ActionController::Metal` to `ActionController::Base`.

You may notice about lack of `respond_with` call. That's because I'm using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) as my template system.

So the question is: Is there any chances to make `rescue_from` work with `Metal` or get rid HTML from response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::Metal
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::Rescue

  append_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views').to_s
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :four_oh_four

  def four_oh_four
    render file: Rails.root.join("public", "404.html"), status: 404
  end
end
```

Comment: Great. It's helped me. Sorry for late response.