# ActionController::Metal How to catch all exceptions to send notification email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ActionController::Metal inherted controllers for for rails services, I want to catch all exceptions , So that I can notify myself through email

`rescue_from Exception` is not working

I have used above code in another app in application controller it is working good But not in this case

Which module should be included in to base controller in order to use it any help?

Code:

```
  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    Rails.logger.warn "\n-EXCEPTION OCCURE IN APPLICATION-\n============\n-On\n-#{Time.now}\n======\nRequest-refer\n#{request.referer}\n=====\nrequest.xhr?\n#{request.xhr?}\n=======\nRequest environment\n#{request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]}\n====\n-MESSAGE\n-#{exception.message}\n======\n-Url\n-#{request.url} \n============\n-Backtrace\n-#{exception.backtrace}"
  end
```

Comment: Possibly `include ActionController::Rescue`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976146/handling-activerecordrecordnotfound-with-actioncontrollermetal

Comment: @7stud yes tried it but nothing happned

Comment: What exception are you not able to catch?

Comment: @7stud Now it worked for me to catch exceptions, just restarted the server my bad ..Thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this speaks to your exact problem, or whether you really need to create this yourself, but if you're open to additional dependencies I use the [exception_notifier gem](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) for this.

Comment: yes that also good but here was looking for custom exception handling rather than any wrapper, otherwise I can also use new-relic as well which awesome ..